Doing a likelihood ratio test.
The question is, It may be interesting to assume that the scale and location parameters are related by some
constant scalar for a normal distribution. Let x1, . . . , xn
iid∼Normal(θ, γθ) and y1, . . . , yn
iid∼Normal(θ, γθ2
).
In both cases, assume that θ is some unknown nuisance parameter.
(a) (15 points) Test H0 : γ = 1 and H1 : γ ̸= 1. Find the likelihood ratio test for each of the above
families (jointly). Simplify your answer as much as possible.
i know the general framework of what to do, but im finding it impossible to implement, i know to make a joint likelihood under the null and then under the alternative, but I am pulling my hair out algbraically solving for MLES for theta and gamma under either hypothesis to plug into the likelihood ratio test statistic, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Hello and welcome to Math.SE. Please use MathJax to write formulas and symbols. It's way easier then copy-pasting each symbol, it's easier to reed and normed. Also please include more details like, where does the question come from and what's your motivation behind asking this. You can find more informatons here.

Before asking any question search it in Approach zero Website https://approach0.xyz/search/
